# Error logged while trying to run Robot Test in IE11 - WebDriverException: 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-11, robotframework, selenium-iedriver

I'm trying to execute certain tests in Robot framework - tests that are working fine with Chrome using the Chrome Driver.

Once execution starts, I get an exception in the command prompt and execution stops without the browser even opening (Attaching the log.html file screenshot and snippet)

```
Suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">;
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Specifications:

1. IE 11
2. IEDriverServer.exe for 64 bit machine
3. Windows 7 64 bit system
4. **Selenium version** 2.53
5. **Robot version** 3.0
6. **Python version** 2.7.11
7. **IEDriverServer** - 2.53.1

---

Been stuck with this issue for the past 4 days. I tried searching many forums and pages on the internet with all possible combinations of keywords, but no luck. :(

Please, tell me how I can proceed with this issue.

Thanks.

[WebdriverException - IEDriverServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geymk.jpg)

I don't have a separate Test Setup. I just use a Suite Setup as below:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation Execution: Performance Validations 
Resource    Performance_Tests_Resource.txt 
Suite Setup    Open Web Browser 
Suite Teardown     Close Browser
```

where my *Open Web Browser* keyword has the following:

```
Open Web Browser 
    Open Browser    ${URLGoogle}    ${BROWSER} 
    Maximize Browser Window
```

and I pass ${BROWSER} as a command line variable

**EDIT** - The problem seems to be with IE11, because if I uninstall the IE11 and IE10 updates and try to start execution with IE8, it works just fine!

Comment: Might be helpful to post your test setup code

Answer (score 1):

> For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

Source https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration